# how to find out the work of a thread in Percentage?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two Years experience in C# programming i have a question regarding thread . Is it possible to find out the work of a thread.

Ex:- In my Application running on thread A, when Thread A complete its 20% work thread B is Started and when Thread B complete their 50% work Thread C is Strated.

So i want to know How Can i Check that Thread A and B work In percentage.
this question is ask me from an interview so i don't know exactly  the Question is in the right manner regarding thread.

help me out 
Shashank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, threads A and B have to *publicise* how much work they've done somehow. This could be:

- Through an event raised by the thread periodically. (That's the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) approach, for example, using the [`ReportProgess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) method and the [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.)
- Through removing work items from a thread-safe collection, so an observing thread can see how much is left and compare it with how much was present to start with
- By encapsulating the work of the thread within an object which allows the "work done" to be queried at any time, whatever that means for the task in question

Of course, all of this assumes the progress can even be computed in the first place...

Comment: I have a confusion Suppose i m on a windows Application So we started From Main STA Thread A The Complete life cycle of Application is Dependent Of thread A how Can we Check the Limited(% work )of Thread A or it may be aplies only in the condition when we create new thread B and Check only B work

Comment: @Damboo: `BackgroundWorker` sounds like it's *probably* appropriate here - but does thread A *know* what proportion of work it's completed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BackgroundWorker to achieve that, in combination with ProgressBar control. For a tutorial, check this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)

What you can do with BackgroundWorker you can also do with simple Threads, but background worker has certain functionality built-in.

Although you mentioned using two threads explicitly, it might clarify things with you if you start with simpler examples like BackgroundWorker.